# Download Page Txt using webclient vb.net

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, webclient

Im trying to download a simple web page as text using `Weblcient` but all time i get a problem,

i think the problem in the `user-agent` but when i set one for the `weblclient` i get the same problem

the page httpheader Capture :

```
GET /wp-json/binlist/v1/441442/?_wpnonce=335f68c9e2 HTTP/1.1
Host: binlist.org:443
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1639241798.1540059335
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,         like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.0.1617 Safari/537.36

HTTP/1.1 200
access-control-allow-headers: Authorization, Content-Type
access-control-expose-headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
allow: GET
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=86400; v="43,39"
cache-control: max-age=0
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 221
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
date: Sat, 22 Jun 2019 10:02:14 GMT
expires: Sat, 22 Jun 2019 10:02:13 GMT
host-header: 192fc2e7e50945beb8231a492d6a8024
link: <https://binlist.org/wp-json></https:>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
server: nginx
set-cookie: wpSGCacheBypass=0; expires=Sat, 22-Jun-2019 09:02:13 GMT; Max-            Age=0; path=/
status: 200
 vary: Accept-Encoding
x-cache-enabled: True
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-proxy-cache: MISS
x-robots-tag: noindex
x-wp-nonce: 335f68c9e2
```

my code :

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    webClient.Headers("User-Agent") = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox/11.0 (via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy)"
    Dim result As String = WebClient.DownloadString("https://binlist.org/wp-json/binlist/v1/441442/?_wpnonce=a7ddc554d3")
    RichTextBox3.Text = result
End Sub
```

Comment: Add `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` before the WebClient initialization.

Comment: i tried add this but i got the sam problem ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls,, or there is a library to import ?

Comment: `ServicePointManager` is part of System.Net. As is WebClient. Re-read the previous comment: I didn't write `SecurityProtocolType.Tls`.

Comment: but i cant find it ? what i should import to work for me ?

Comment: You cannot find what, exactly? `SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`? You need to  target at least .Net framework version 4.5. Possibly, use .Net FW 4.7.1+

Comment: i have add it before webclient declaration but i ahve the same problem

Comment: *The same problem*? What problem would that be? That site returns a very simple JSON file and the only requirement is the TLS 1.2 handshake. You don't need anything else. Remove that 10 years-old User-Agent thing (which is not needed either) and try again. The only *problem* you can have is if you have a proxy to pass through.

Comment: its work fine thanks you